# My panel OnRender is not called when children are invisible

Tags: c#, wpf, custom-controls

I have a custom panel that plots points of interest and templated labels for them.  The custom panel then draws a leader line from the point of interest to the label.

I override `MeasureOverride`, `ArrangeOverride` and `OnRender` to handle different events:

- MeasureOverride: calculate the size of all the children within my floor plan, as well as their associated label sizes
- ArrangeOverride: place the items on the floor plan, disambiguate labels and place them as well.
- OnRender: draw leader lines from the point of interest to the associated label

In the normal cases everything is working just fine:

- Before any children are added, nothing is drawn to the screen
- As children are added, the leader lines appear
- If I move my visual extent (view into the larger overall floor plan), the labels will continue to shift to avoid collisions with the edges or each other.  The leader lines are all updated appropriately.

In one case it does not work:

- If I remove all the children, or mark them all invisible, the OnRender is never called so the last leader line happens to remain on screen.  It is never updated as I move my visual extent.

The relevant properties are marked with the `FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsParentArrange` or `FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender`.  I even manually call `InvalidateVisual()` from the callback I added to the InternalChildren structure.

The problem seems to be that WPF has made an optimization that OnRender will not be called if all the children are zero sized or simply not there.  That means the last leader line can't be called.

If that's the case, how do I work around it?

OK, I hand jammed the code subset that was exported from our private network into GitHub.  If there are errors compiling it, I apologize and will attempt to address it after I get home where I have a compiler on a machine with internet access.

The GitHubRepository: https://github.com/bloritsch/WpfRenderIssue

The master branch demonstrates the problem, and the Kluge-Fix demonstrates my answer (all of one line of code...).

WARNING: sizeable code is included below.

Main Window XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfRenderIssue.MainWIndow"
    <!-- namespace declarations here -->
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
          <RowDefinition/>
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>

      <ToggleButton x:Name="Toggle" IsChecked="True">Show/Hide</ToggleButton>
      <project:FloorPlanLayout x:Name="Layout" Grid.Row="1" LabelOffset="20" LeaderThickness="2">
          <project:FloorPlanLayout.LabelTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                  <Border Background="#80008000" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                      <TextBlock Margin="3" FontSize="16" FontWeight="SemiBold" Text="{Binding Path=(project:FloorPlanLayout.Label), Mode=OneWay}"
                          Foreground="{Binding Path=(project:FloorPlanLayout.LabelBrush), Mode=OneWay}"/>
                  </Border>
              </DataTemplate>
          </project:FloorPlanLayout.LabelTemplate>
      </project:FloorPlanLayout>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Main Window Code-Behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // The layout control is typically used with items
        // generated from data, and added after loading.
        // We'll just hard code the one element to show the problem

        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle
        {
            Width = 30,
            Height = 30,
            Fill = Brushes.DodgerBlue
        };

        Canvas.SetLeft(rectangle, 100);
        Canvas.SetTop(rectangle, 50);
        FloorPlanLayout.SetLabel(rectangle, "Test Label");
        FloorPlanLayout.SetLabelBrush(rectangle, Brushes.Black);

        BindingOperations.SetBinding(rectangle, VisibilityProperty, new Binding
        {
            Source = Toggle,
            Path = new PropertyPath(ToggleButton.IsCheckedProperty),
            Converter = new BooleanToVisibilityConverter()
        });

        Layout.Children.Add(rectangle);
    }
}
```

OK, so now for the big class....

FloorPlanLayout:

```
public class FloorPlanLayout : Canvas
{
    // Attached properties: 
    public static readonly DependencyProperty LabelProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Label", typeof(string), typeof(FloorPlanLayout),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(string.Empty, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty LabelBrushProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("LabelBrush", typeof(Brush), typeof(FloorPlanLayout),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(Brushes.Transparent, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender | FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsParentArrange));

    // private attached dependency properties
    private static readonly DependencyProperty IsLabelProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsLabel", typeof(bool), typeof(FloorPlanLayout),
            new PropertyMetadata(false));

    private static readonly DependencyProperty LabelPresenterProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsLabel", typeof(ContentProperty), typeof(FloorPlanLayout));

    // public properties
    public static readonly DependencyProperty LabelOffsetProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("LabelOffset", typeof(double), typeof(FloorPlanLayout),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(20.0, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsArrange));

    public static readonly DependentyProperty LabelTemplateProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("LabelTemplate", typeof(DataTemplate), typeof(FloorPlanLayout),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure | FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsArrange));

     public static readonly DependencyProperty LeaderThicknessProperty =
         DependencyProperty.Register("LeaderThickness", typeof(double), typeof(FloorPlanLayout),
             new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(1.0, FrameowrkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));

    // Skipping the boilerplate setters/getters and class properties for
    // brevity and keeping this to the important stuff

    public FloorPlanLayout()
    {
        ClipToBounds = true;
        // NOTE: for completeness I would have to respond to the Loaded
        // event to handle the equivalent callback to create the label
        // presenters for items added directly in XAML due to the XAML
        // initializers circumventing runtime code
    }

    public override UIElementCollection CreateUIElementCollection(FrameworkElement logicalParent)
    {
        NotifyingUIElementCollection collection = new NotifyingUIElementCollection(this, logicalParent);
        collection.CollectionChanged += ChildrenCollectionChanged;
        return collection;
    }

    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
    {
        Size newDesiredSize = new Size(
            (double.IsInfinity(availbleSize.Width) ? double.MaxValue : availableSize.Width),
            (double.IsInfinity(availableSize.Height) ? double.MaxValue : availableSize.Height));

        foreach(UIElement child in InternalChildren)
        {
            child.Measure(availableSize);

            newDesiredSize.Width = Math.Max(newDesiredSize.Width, child.DesiredSize.Width);
            newDesiredSize.Height = Math.Max(newDesiredSize.Height, child.DesiredSize.Height);
        }

        return newDesiredSize;
    }

    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
    {
        foreach(UIElement child in InternalChildren.OfType<UIElement>()
            .Where(e => !GetIsLabel(e))
            .OrderByDescending(GetZIndex))
        {
            Rect plotArea = PositionByCanvasLocationOrIgnore(child, finalSize);

            ContentPresenter labelPresenter = GetLabelPresenter(child);
            Rect labelRect = new Rect(labelPresenter.DesiredSize)
            {
                X = plotArea.Right + LabelOffset,
                Y = plotArea.Y + ((plotArea.Height - labelPresenter.DesiredSize.Height) / 2)
            };

            labelPresenter.Arrange(labelRect);
        }

        return finalSize;
    }

    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
    {
        base.OnRender(drawingContext);
        double dpiFactor = 1;

        if(LabelTemplate == null || LeaderThickness < 0.25)
        {
            // nothing to do if no label template, or leader thickness too small
            return;
        }

        PresentationSource source = PresentationSource.FromVisual(this);
        if(source != null && source.CompositionTarget != null)
        {
            // Adjust for DPI
            Matrix matrix = source.CompositionTarget.TransformToDevice;
            dpiFactor = 1 / matrix.M11;
        }

        foreach(FrameworkElement element in
            InternalChildren.OfType<FrameworkElement>().Where(child => !GetIsLable(child)))
        {
            FrameworkElement label = GetLabelPresenter(element);

            if(label == null || !label.IsVisible || !element.IsVisible)
            {
                // don't draw lines if there are no visible labels
                continue;
            }

            Brush leaderBrush = GetLabelBrush(element);

            if(leaderBrush == null || Equals(leaderBrush, Brushes.Transparent)
            {
                // Don't draw leader if brush is null or transparent
                continue;
            }

            leaderBrush.Freeze();
            Pen linePen = new Pen(leaderBrush, LeaderThickness * dpiFactor);
            linePen.Freeze();

            Rect objectRect = new Rect(element.TranslatePiont(new Point(), this), element.RenderSize);
            Rect labelRect = new Rect(label.TranslatePoint(new Point(), this), label.RenderSize);

            double halfPenWidth = linePen.Thicnkess / 2;

            // Set up snap to pixels
            GuidelineSet guidelines = new GuidelineSet();
            guidelines.GuidelinesX.Add(objectRect.Right + halfPenWidth);
            guidelines.GuidelinesX.Add(labelRect.Left + halfPenWidth);
            guidelines.GuidelinesY.Add(objectRect.Top + halfPenWidth);
            guidelines.GuidelinesY.Add(labelRect.Top + halfPenWidth);

            drawingContext.PushGuidelineSet(guidelines);

            if(objectRect.Width > 0 && labelRect.Width > 0)
            {
                Point startPoint = new Point(objectRect.Right + linePen.Thickness,
                    objectRect.Top + (objectRect.Height / 2));
                Point endPoint = new Point(labelRect.Left,
                    labelRect.Top + (labelRect.Height / 2));

                drawingContext.DrawLine(linePen, startPoint, endPoint);
                drawingContext.DrawLine(linePen, labelRect.TopLeft, labelRect.BottomLeft);
            }

            drawingContext.Pop();
        }
    }

    private static Rect PositionByCanvasLocationOrIgnore(UIElement child, SIze finalSize)
    {
        double left = GetLeft(child);
        double top = GetTop(child);

        if (double.IsNaN(left))
        {
            // if no left anchor calculate from the right
            double right = GetRight(child);
            left = double.IsNaN(right) ? right : finalSize.Width - right - child.DesiredSize.Width;
        }

        if(double.IsNaN(top))
        {
            double bottom = GetBottom(child);
            top = double.IsNaN(top) ? bottom : finalSize.Height - bottom - child.DesiredSize.Height;
        }

        if(double.IsNaN(left) || double.IsNaN(top))
        {
            // if it's still unset, don't position the element
            returnRect.Empty;
        }

        Rect plotArea = new Rect(new Point(left, top), child.DesiredSize);
        child.Arrange(plotArea);
        return plotArea;
    }

    private void ChildrenCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        if(args.OldItems != null)
        {
            foreach(UIElement child in args.OldItems)
            {
                RemoveLabelForElement(child);
            }
        }

        if(args.NewItems != null)
        {
            foreach(UIElement child in args.NewItems)
            {
                CreateLabelForElement(child);
            }
        }

        // Try to clean up leader lines if we remove the last item
        InvalidateVisual();
    }

    private void CreateLabelForElement(UIElement element)
    {
        if(LabelTemplate == null || element == null || GetIsLabel(element))
        {
            // prevent unnecessary work and recursive calls because labels
            // have to be children too.
            return;
        }

        ContentPresenter label = new ContentPresenter
        {
            Content = element
        };

        SetIsLabel(label, true);

        BindingOperations.SetBinding(label, ContentPresenter.ContentTemplateProperty, new Binding
        {
            Source = this,
            Path = new PropertyPath(LabelTemplateProperty),
            Mode = BindingMode.OneWay
        });

        BindingOperations.SetBinding(label, VisibilityProperty, new Binding
        {
            Source = element,
            Path = new PropertyPath(VisibilityProperty),
            Mode = BindingMode.OneWay
        });

        BindingOperations.SetBinding(label, ZIndexProperty, new Binding
        {
            Source = element,
            Path = new PropertyPath(ZIndexProperty),
            Mode = BindingMode.OneWay
        });

        SetLabelPresenter(element, label);
        Children.Add(label);
    }

    private void RemoveLabelForElement(UIElement element)
    {
        if (element == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        ContentPresenter label = GetLabelPresenter(element);

        if(label == null)
        {
            // true if we never added a label, and if the element was a label to begin with
            return true;
        }

        BindingOperations.ClearBinding(label, ContentPresenter.ContentTemplateProperty);
        BindingOperations.ClearBinding(label, VisibilityProperty);
        BindingOperations.ClearBinding(label, ZIndexProperty);

        Children.Remove(label);
        SetLabelPresenter(element, null);
    }
}
```

The last object really isn't that important to the problem.  It's the NotifyingUIElementCollection:

```
public class NotifyingUIElementCollection : UIElementCollection
{
    public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;

    public NotifyingUIElementCollection(UIElement visualParent, FrameworkElement logicalParent)
        : base(visualParent, logicalParent)
    {}

    public override int Add(UIElement element)
    {
        int index = base.Add(element);
        OnNotifyCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, element);
        return index;
    }

    public override void Clear()
    {
        base.Clear();
        OnNotifyCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset, null);
    }

    public override void Remove(UIElement element)
    {
        base.Remove(element);
        OnNotifyCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove, element);
    }

    public override void RemoveAt(int index)
    {
       base.RemoveAt(index);
       OnNotifyCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove, this[index]);
    }

    public override void RemoveRange(int index, int count)
    {
        UIElement[] itemsRemoved = this.OfType<UIElement>().Skip(index).Take(count).ToArray();
        base.RemoveRange(index, count);
        OnNotifyCollectionCnaged(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove, itemsRemoved);
    }

    private void OnNotifyCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedAction action, params UIElement[] items)
    {
        if(CollectionChanged != null)
        {
            CollectionChanged(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(action, items));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Invisible in what way?  They are collapsed, or hidden, or is their size changed?

Comment: _"the size of the relevant code parts are too large and proprietary to place here"_ -- no one wants you (or anyone) to post the actual code. You need to create and include [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem.

Comment: Invisible as in collapsed or hidden.  @PeterDuniho, Not sure how to separate out a small example.  I'll see what I can do.

Comment: As to those who voted to close the question, what was your reason for the vote?

Comment: Code snippets to follow soon.  I had to rip out proprietary bits while still showing the problem.  It's being reviewed at the moment.

Comment: Added the code snippets.  Should be enough to reproduce the issue, but I left out boilerplate code that everyone knows how to do themselves.  This is very much simplified from the original code.

Comment: FloorPlanLayout doesn't compile as posted. It has typos, and even correcting for typos, it isn't self-contained... If you can't post something concise, then perhaps post something that will actually compile and can be debugged.

Comment: `FloorPlanLayout` has multiple cut-off lines that look like this : `BindingOperations.SetBinding(label, VisibilityProperty, new Binding`.

Comment: @jstreet, sorry about that, it's the occupational hazard of copying code by hand from a machine on another network.  The lines continue on and are merely missing the closing parenthesis after the closing bracket (}).  Object initializer syntax doesn't require the () if there are no parameters to pass in to the constructor.

Comment: Also, you have the source code, stop down voting just because it's a hard problem.  Give me a reason.

Comment: Can you use `Visibility.Hidden` or set `Opacity=0` (with Visibility.Visible)? That should get around any perf optimizations. The items will still take up space though, which might be an issue for you.

Comment: I can try it.  The BooleanToVisibilityConverter supplied in WPF proper toggles between collapsed and visible, and it's more likely to be used.

Comment: I will try and get the mini-project on GitHub soon to make it easier to play with.

Comment: Neither of those options made a difference, but it did show one more thing I had to account for...  Changes in Opacity don't get reflected in the label.  While it's not something we are currently using it would be unexpected if we changed our minds on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a kluge of an answer, so if anyone has a more elegant solution please let me know.  After setting break points on OnRender and ArrangeOverride, I took a look at some flags that control the measure/arrange/render callbacks that are deep in the bowels of Panel and UIElement.

I discovered that after arranging my children, the visual was not always invalidated.  This is just one case where it was painfully obvious.  The solution in this case is to always call InvalidateVisual() at the end of ArrangeOverride().

```
protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
{
    foreach(UIElement child in InternalChildren.OfType<UIElement>()
        .Where(e => !GetIsLabel(e))
        .OrderByDescending(GetZIndex))
    {
        Rect plotArea = PositionByCanvasLocationOrIgnore(child, finalSize);

        ContentPresenter labelPresenter = GetLabelPresenter(child);
        Rect labelRect = new Rect(labelPresenter.DesiredSize)
        {
            X = plotArea.Right + LabelOffset,
            Y = plotArea.Y + ((plotArea.Height - labelPresenter.DesiredSize.Height) / 2)
        };

        labelPresenter.Arrange(labelRect);
    }

    // NEW CODE: force the visual to be redrawn every time.
    InvalidateVisual();

    return finalSize;
}
```

This is, of course, very heavy handed.  As long as we are only updating the floorplan once a second like we are now, we'll be OK.  Continuous updates will be a problem.

Again, this solution does work but it is far from ideal.  Hopefully it can help someone get an even better answer for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to `InvalidateVisual()` unless the size of your control changes.

If you just want to repaint the UI of your control... Place a `DrawingGroup` into the visual-tree during `OnRender()`, then whenever you want you can `DrawingGroup.Open()` and change the drawing commands in the `DrawingGroup`. You would do this whenever the children collection changes.

It looks something like this:

```
DrawingGroup backingStore = new DrawingGroup();

protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext) {      
    base.OnRender(drawingContext);            

    Render(); // put content into our backingStore
    drawingContext.DrawDrawing(backingStore);
}

// I can call this anytime, and it'll update my visual drawing
// without ever triggering layout or OnRender()
private void Render() {            
    var drawingContext = backingStore.Open();
    Render(drawingContext);
    drawingContext.Close();            
}
```